# How do I correc the runtime error Stack around the variable was corrupted?

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime

I am working on a madlibs program using pointers. When I try to build it does so correctly, but I think their is some trouble with dynamically allocated array used to store the lines from the text file that is read in. The umber that goes in the array is a sentinel value in the file. I also left in the cout statements to show it store the information before the error .Can Any help? The error is the stack around "entries".

//here is my code so far

```
#include <iostream>       
#include <string>         
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>




using namespace std;

void header();
//string play_again();
void read_game_file(string **entries, int *num_entries, string **story, int *num_lines);
//string get_user_input(string* entries, int * num_entries);

int main()
{

    header();
    cout<<endl<<endl;

    int num_entries=(NULL);
    int *num_lines=(NULL);
    string *entries (NULL);
    string *story (NULL);

    read_game_file( &entries,  &num_entries,  &story,   &*num_lines);
    cout<<"doneszo"<<endl;
    string get_user_input(string*entries, int * num_entries);


}

void header()
{
     cout<<"Hello! Welcome to the game Madlibs."<<endl;
     cout<<"The object of the game is to produce something that sounds totally ridiculous."<<endl;
     cout<<"So don't think to hard about your answers."<<endl;
     cout<<"At the top, you will see a bunch of word descriptions followed by blank spaces."<<endl;
     cout<<"Type your word in the blanks. The words should match the descriptions on the left."<<endl;
     cout<<"Enter no when you no longer wish to play. Enter yes to continue. Have a great laugh!"<<endl;
 }

void read_game_file(string **entries, int *num_entries, string **story, int *num_lines)
{
     //Ask user to input file name and opens file
     ifstream mad_lib;
     string file_name;

     cout<<"Please enter the file name with extension: ";
     cin>>file_name;
     mad_lib.open(file_name);

     //Checks to see that file name is valid if not ask for input again
     if (!mad_lib)
     {
        cout<<"File could not be opened. Please try again"<<endl;
        cout<<"Please enter the file name with extension: ";
        cin>>file_name;
        mad_lib.open(file_name);
        }

     int work;
     string line;
     mad_lib>>work;
     num_entries=&work;
     getline(mad_lib,line);

     *entries=new string[*num_entries];
     cout<<*num_entries<<endl;
     string * entry;
     for(int i=0; i<*num_entries; i++)
     {
         entry = new string;
         getline(mad_lib,*entry);
         entries[i]= entry;
         cout<<*(entries[i])<<endl;
     }


     string work_2;
     int work_3;
     stringstream ss;
     getline(mad_lib,work_2);
     ss<<work_2;
     ss>>work_3;
     cout<<work_2<<endl;
     num_lines=&work_3;
     *story=new string[*num_lines];
     string *entry_2;

     for(int j=0; j<=*num_lines; j++)
     {
         entry_2=new string;
         getline(mad_lib,*entry_2);
         story[j]= entry_2;
         cout<<*(story[j])<<endl;
     }

}
```

Comment: You should avoid that `**` and `new` stuff. Won't an `std::vector<std::string>` do?

Comment: `entries[i]= entry;` is your problem. any value of i bigger than 0 will corrupt the stack. try using `(*entries)[i]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pointers in function arguments until necessary.

Use pass by reference and const instead.

Another question to ask yourself - do you really want `read_game_file` to "fill" up some data in its arguments? Can you design it better? Here, you have a bunch of variables defined in `main`, and you expect `read_game_file` to "fill" them for you.

You should instead encapsulate this functionality within a class. Pass in the file name as argument to the class's `ReadFile(const string& filename)` method. All of this data should be in the class.

To solve your immediate problem (in the unclean way):

```
void read_game_file(string **entries, int *num_entries, string **story, int *num_lines);
```

should be

```
void read_game_file(vector<string>& entries, int& num_entries, vector<string>& story, int& num_lines);


int main()
{

    header();
    cout << endl << endl; // spaces help readability!

    int num_entries = 0;
    int num_lines = 0;
    vector<string> entries;
    vector<string> story;

    read_game_file( &entries,  &num_entries,  &story,   &*num_lines);
    cout << "doneszo"<< endl;
    string get_user_input(vector<string>& entries, int& num_entries);
}
```

Use vectors instead of arrays. They're elegant and clean to use.
I'll leave the function for you to complete.

Comment: Thanks  everyone for your help. I figured out how to fix it.